# Twitter bootstrap mobile menu - uncollapsed state as default

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, joomla2.5

I am using the Joomla Master Bootstrap template.  It is built around the Twitter bootsrap.

Now, when it is in mobile view, I want to keep the mobile menu in open state.  In other words, the mobile dropdown menu view must be uncollapsed as a default state and close when a user clicks the button.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Here is what the default state looks like:

[image]

And here is what I want, as default:

[image]

Thanks

JG

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle? This should be a very easy problem to solve. Usually you only have to give it a class to let it stay open, but I'm not sure in Joomla Master Bootstrap.

Comment: @Chanckjh What class would you usually use to keep it open?  Thanks JG

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.nav-collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('in collapse').css("height","auto"); 
});
```